# Use ChatGPT trough Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, openai-api, power-automate, chatgpt-api

I was trying to use the API of chat gpt to connect it to a chat on teams. I've found something,

[THIS](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Webinars-and-Video-Gallery/Learn-how-to-add-ChatGPT-to-Microsoft-Teams/td-p/1986363)

In the guide above it is shown how to do it by using power automate to connect the api of chatGPT to a channel on teams,seems pretty easy but in some parts isn't clear, in fact i've done everything that the guide says but at the end of it the tutorial guy does this:
[SCREEN OF THE VIDEO GUIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8oFX.png)
for some reasons i can't manage to do the same thing, instead i receive an error, this one:
[SCREEN OF MY RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbO4q.png)

Other people have encountered this issue but none of them solved it or haven't received an help from the guy of the tutorial, someone may have encountered this issue too in here?

I've followed the tutorial, searched for answers in the comment section, asked to ChatGPT how to figure it out but nothing of it worked out.

Comment: The product group for Power automate actively monitors questions in dedicated forums here. 
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Power-Automate/ct-p/MPACommunity. 
Could you please raise this issue here.